# The procedure works in MySQL 5, but fails in MySQL6, why?

Tags: mysql, procedure, mysql6

Procedure:

```
delimiter |
create procedure  pro_regs(in username varchar(50), 
                           in pwd varchar(50), 
                           in email varchar(50), 
                           in address varchar(50)) 
  begin  

     insert into regists 
       ( `user_name` , `user_psd` , `user_email` , `user_address`)
     values
       (username, pwd, email, address);

  end|
```

Does anyone know?

Comment: How does the procedure fail? Error message? Not the expected output?

Comment: Failed to create the procedure.

Answer (score 2):

From your descriptions it's impossible to answer, but you might find this helpful.

> Stored routines require the proc table
>   in the mysql database. This table is
>   created during the MySQL 6.0
>   installation procedure. If you are
>   upgrading to MySQL 6.0 from an earlier
>   version, be sure to update your grant
>   tables to make sure that the proc 
>   table exists.

I must ask if you are aware of the fact that MySQL 6 isn't being developed anymore?

> The MySQL 6.0 Reference Manual has
>   been retired.
>
> MySQL 6.0 was not developed beyond
>   Alpha status and new releases have not
>   been made for some time, so the manual
>   has been withdrawn as well.
>
> New development is currently focused
>   on MySQL 5.4. For more information,
>   see MySQL 5.4 Reference Manual.

References [Manual](http://sunsite.mff.cuni.cz/MIRRORS/ftp.mysql.com/doc/refman/6.0/en/stored-routines.html) | [Notice](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/6.0/en/index.html)

Comment: Why it's not being developed anymore?

Comment: The stuff for MySQL 6.0 was moved into either earlier or later releases; the work done is still going to be released eventually. MySQL 6.0 will never exist in non-alpha version.